# "cannot allocate memory" error when trying to create folder in cgroup hierarchy

Tags: memory, cgroups

we ran into an interesting bug today.  on our servers we put users into cgroup folders to monitor + control usage of resources like cpu and memory.  we started getting errors when trying to add user-specific memory cgroup folders:

```
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/users/newuser
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/users/newusers’: Cannot allocate memory
```

That seemed a little strange, because the machine actually had a reasonable amount of free memory and swap.  Changing the `sysctl` values for `vm.overcommit_memory` from 0 to 1 had no effect.

We did notice that we were running with quite a lot of user-specific subfolders (about 7,000 in fact), and most of them were for users that were no longer running processes on that machine.

```
ls /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/users/ | wc -l
7298
```

deleting unused folders in the cgroup hierarchy actually fixed the problem

```
cd /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/users/
ls | xargs -n1 rmdir
# errors for folders in-use, succeeds for unused
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/users/newuser
# now works fine
```

interestingly, the problem only affected the memory cgroup.  the cpu/accounting cgroup was fine, even though it actually had more users in the hierarchy:

```
ls /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/users/ | wc -l
7450
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/users/newuser
# fine
```

So, what was causing these out-of-memory errors?  Does the memory-cgroup subsystem itself have some sort of memory limit of its own?

contents of cgroup mounts may be found [here](https://pastebin.com/tkmw60Df)

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed limits per cgroup, you can read about them [on LWN.net](https://lwn.net/Articles/529927/):

> Each cgroup has a memory controller
>   specific data structure (mem_cgroup) associated with it.
>
> .... Accounting happens per cgroup.

The maximum amount of memory is stored in */sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes*. If the problem you experienced was really connected with *cgroup* memory limit, then */sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max_usage_in_bytes* should be close to the above, which you can also check by inspecting *memory.failcnt*, which records the number of times your actual usage hit the limit above.

Perhaps you may also check *memory.kmem.failcnt* and *memory.kmem.tcp.failcnt* for similar statistics on kernel memory and tcp buffer memory.

Comment: i'm not sure you've understood the question.  the error i'm getting seems to be coming from the operating system when I'm trying to create a new cgroups folder -- it's not about the limits applied to any particular cgroup.  correct me if i've misunderstood, myself...

Comment: to answer your question, the top-level `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory` folder has the following: `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max_usage_in_bytes =
14010560512`, 
`/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes = 9223372036854771712` (ie max usage 8 orders of magnitude under limit)